# How to fix "ImportError: Pandas >= 0.19.2 must be installed; however, it was not found"?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 2.3.1 and want to use `toPandas()` (to use `unique()`).

When I execute the following code in `pyspark`:

```
df.toPandas()['column_01'].unique()
```

I'm facing the following exception:

```
>>> df.toPandas()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/xxx/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 2075, in toPandas
    require_minimum_pandas_version()
  File "/Users/xxx/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 129, in require_minimum_pandas_version
    "it was not found." % minimum_pandas_version)
ImportError: Pandas >= 0.19.2 must be installed; however, it was not found.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You would need to install pandas:  `pip install pandas` .
Also, to get the unique values, you don't need to convert to pandas dataframe. You can achieve that in spark dataframe.

`df.select('column_01').distinct()`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I recently struggled with the same problem when deploying a pyspark job to Google Dataproc. The solution that worked for me was the following:

When creating the cluster, specify the following:

```
--metadata 'PIP_PACKAGES=pandas==0.23.0'
```